# Solr Cloud Kerberos cookie rejected spnego

Tags: solr, kerberos, solrcloud, spnego, httpcookie

Enabled `solrcloud-7.4.0` with `kerberos`. While creating a collection getting below error

```
org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator; NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))) 
org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies; Cookie rejected [hadoop.auth="", version:0, domain:xxx.xxx.com, path:/, expiry:xxxx Illegal domain attribute "<FQDN>". Domain of origin: "localhost"
```

enabled krb5 debug true and am able to find the actual problem is that sname is HTTP/localhost@REALM.COM, it should be HTTP/@DOMAIN1.COM not the localhost

Please help me out!

Tried `-Dsolr.kerberos.cookie.domain=<FQDN>` in `solr.in.sh`

solr.in.sh

```
SOLR_AUTH_TYPE="kerberos"
SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-DauthenticationPlugin=org.apache.solr.security.KerberosPlugin -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/solr/jaas.conf -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dsolr.kerberos.cookie.domain=<FQDN> -Dsolr.kerberos.name.rules=DEFAULT -Dsolr.kerberos.principal=HTTP/<FQDN>@DOMAIN1.COM -Dsolr.kerberos.keytab=/solr/HTTP.keytab"


org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator; NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))) 
org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies; Cookie rejected [hadoop.auth="", version:0, domain:xxx.xxx.com, path:/, expiry:xxxx Illegal domain attribute "<FQDN>". Domain of origin: "localhost"
```

enabled krb5 debug true and am able to find the actual problem is that sname is HTTP/localhost@REALM.COM, it should be HTTP/@DOMAIN1.COM not the localhost

Comment: [According to the documentation of the Kerberos Authentication Plugin](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/kerberos-authentication-plugin.html#KerberosAuthenticationPlugin-ServicePrincipalsandKeytabFiles), that's the expected format, since it contains the host name of the host being authenticated in the service principal.

Comment: oops! Typo mistake !!  enabled krb5 debug true and am able to find the actual problem is that sname is HTTP/localhost@REALM.COM, it should be HTTP/<FQDN>@DOMAIN1.COM not the localhost

Comment: My guess is that the hostname is determine by the actual hostname given to the _server itself_. If running `hostname` on the server gives `localhost`, that's probably your issue.

Comment: hostname command output  is FQDN only not the localhost